# Find minimum of two different groupedby columns in Python

Tags: python, min, group

I am just starting to learn python and have not been able to find the answer to this anywhere.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(df.groupby(['State', 'County', 'Family']).AP.agg(Minimum = ("min"),
                                                  Maximum = ("max"),
                                                  Sum = ("sum"),
                                                  Volume = ("count"),
                                                  Average = ("mean"),
                                                  Mode = (lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
                                                  ).reset_index().round(0))
```

Now I need to add a column that has the minimum of the average and mode columns, is this possible?

So for example:

| State | County | Family | Minimum | Maximum | Sum | Volume | Average | Mode | Min of Avg & Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FL | ALACHUA | Interior | 400 | 500 | 5025 | 12 | 419.0 | 400 | 400 |
| FL | WALTON | Interior | 500 | 1400 | 10432 | 14 | 515.0 | 550 | 515 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.where() to select the smaller value of 2 columns.

```
import numpy as np

df['Min of Avg & Mode'] = np.where(df['Average'] > df['Mode'], df['Mode'], df['Average'])
```